# Will values in function generate every time?

Tags: scala

```
  object isValidUuid {
    val sample = "f40473b8-9924-2a9a-bd82-7432191f2a75"
    val len = sample.length
    val dashIndices = sample.indices.filter(sample(_) == '-')

    def apply(string: String) = {
      string.length == len && dashIndices.forall(string(_) == '-')
    }
  }

  def isValidUuid(string: String) = {
    //f40473b8-9924-2a9a-bd82-7432191f2a75
    val sample = "f40473b8-9924-2a9a-bd82-7432191f2a75"
    val len = sample.length
    val dashIndices = sample.indices.filter(sample(_) == '-')
    string.length == len && dashIndices.forall(string(_) == '-')
  }
```

Did the object and function isValidUuid do exactly the same thing,
or object will be faster,because function calculate len and dashIndices every time?

Answer (score 2):

This scala code:

```
object O {
  val i = 1

  def foo = {
    i
  }

  def bar = {
    val x = 1
    x
  }
}
```

Compiles to this java:

```
public class _$$anon$1$O$ {
  private final int i;

  public int i() {
    return this.i;
  }

  public int foo() {
    return this.i();
  }

  public int bar() {
    final int x = 1;
    return x;
  }

  {
    this.i = 1;
  }
}
// lazy object initialization omitted
```

As you can see, all values inside the function are transpiled into local variables, while values inside the object are class fields and they are initialized only once (when object is initialized). I omitted object initialization code for clarity.

Check my [scala-to-java](https://github.com/Aivean/scala-to-java) tool, it helps to understand how scala works in such cases.

Comment: Different versions of scala might give result,what version of scalac do you use?

Comment: @Renkai correct, but not for this particular case. This was compiled with scalac v2.11.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy test this, adding sleep to your lenght calculation

```
  object isValidUuidObj {
    val sample = "f40473b8-9924-2a9a-bd82-7432191f2a75"
    val len = {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      sample.length
    }
    val dashIndices = sample.indices.filter(sample(_) == '-')

    def apply(string: String) = {
      string.length == len && dashIndices.forall(string(_) == '-')
    }
  }

  def isValidUuid(string: String) = {
    //f40473b8-9924-2a9a-bd82-7432191f2a75
    val sample = "f40473b8-9924-2a9a-bd82-7432191f2a75"
    val len = {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      sample.length
    }
    val dashIndices = sample.indices.filter(sample(_) == '-')
    string.length == len && dashIndices.forall(string(_) == '-')
  }
```

Yes, object will be faster, but I don't think that in your case this difference is important.
You'd better keep all constants in object (magic numbers/strings are always bad idea), while using object for calculations is not a clean solution.

Comment: The function version could be optimized to the object version in the compile time.What I wondering more is that if this optimize is currently implemented in scala compiler,or such optimize is impossible to implement   for some reason

Comment: @Renkai such optimization is impossible, as otherwise scala compiler must be aware of all possible side effects of the variable initialization code. Simple example, when you have `val i = getUUID()`, how can scala compiler know, whether `getUUID()` has side effects or not and if it is safe to not invoke this function each time. Constants probably could be optimized, but I doubt that it's implemented.